# Next Js Cannot fill database with data using an internal POST API

Tags: javascript, rest, next.js, next-api

```
<div className={styles.Panier}>
     <p onClick={()=>Quantity>0?NewItem(data,Quantity):console.log("Quantity must be more 
     than 0")}>Add To Cart</p>
</div>
```

When Clicking on the that div the following `NewItem` function gets executed:

```
    let NewItem = async (data,Qte) => {
        const response = await fetch('/api/UpdateCart',{
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    Qte,
                    data,
                    cartId: Cookies.get('cart')
                }
            ),
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf8'
            },
        });
        console.log(response);
    };
```

This normally should go to the api in '/api/UpdateCart' (I'm using prisma btw):

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";


export default async function handler(req, res)
{
    let prisma = new PrismaClient();
    let Id = req.body.Id;
    let Qte = req.body.Qte;
    let cartId = req.body.cartId;
    //Creates the new item and adds it to the cart
    let newItem = await prisma.item.create({
        data: {
            ProductId: Id,
            Quantity: Qte,
            CartId: cartId
        }
    });
    return res.status(200).json(newItem);
}
```

Now the problem is that when i try the endpoint in postman it works like a charm, but when i use access it from the `NewItem` function that i mentionned before, I get a 500 server error in the following way:

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/UpdateCart 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/UpdateCart', redirected: false, status: 500, ok: false, …}
body
: 
(...)
bodyUsed
: 
false
headers
: 
Headers {}
ok
: 
false
redirected
: 
false
status
: 
500
statusText
: 
"Internal Server Error"
type
: 
"basic"
url
: 
"http://localhost:3000/api/UpdateCart"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Response
```

I hope that u can help me and thank you for your time

Comment: in the `fetch` request you have `Qte, data, cartId` while in the API endpoint you're reading an undefined value of `req.body.Id` used in `ProductId`

Comment: @mocherfaoui Thank you for your time but it didn't work even after i fixed it; the thing is that when i try the url in postman it executes correctly and adds a record to the db as it's supposed to do, but whenever i use that same endpoint in a fetch from the front-end side it keeps giving me that server error 'code 500 '.

Comment: if it works in postman then it might be that a some value of the request body(`Qte, data, cartId`) is undefined or something. can you do a `console.log` for each one of them before they're sent to the endpoint?

Comment: this is the console's output:                                                                                 Request: Qte=>2 | ProductId=>1 | cartId=>31
Inside the Api Endpoint: Qte=>2 | ProductId=>1 | cartId=>31.     The problem is that this works when i  comment out the bits of code where i save the data into the database!! When i uncomment it, even the console.log stops working. So i guess the problem is with the database saving

Comment: @mocherfaoui Thank you so much for your time man, I actually found the solution, I posted the answer down below and after the 12 hours countdown I'm going to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than a day of searching i found out that the problem was actually in API code since i was having one-to-many relationships I was supposed to 'connect' the full 'Cart' and 'Product' records into my item record.

***1. This is the API code before the solution:***

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";


export default async function handler(req, res)
{
   let prisma = new PrismaClient();
   let Id = req.body.Id;
   let Qte = req.body.Qte;
   let cartId = req.body.cartId;
   //Creates the new item and adds it to the cart
   let newItem = await prisma.item.create({
       data: {
           ProductId: Id,
           Quantity: Qte,
           CartId: cartId
       }
   });
   return res.status(200).json(newItem);
}
```

***2. This is the Correct API code:***

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async (req, res) => {
  
  let PrId = req.body.prodId;
  let Qte = req.body.Qte;
  let newItem = await prisma.item.create({
    data:{
      Quantity: Qte,
      Product:{
        connect:{
          Id: PrId,
        },
      }, 
      Cart:{
        connect:{
          Id: req.body.cartId
        }
      }
    },
  });

  return res.status(200).json(newItem);
};
```